# Long table header vertical alignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, rotating

Consider the example, with two long headings to a table (one is longer):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{|C{2em}|C{2em}|}\hline
            \rotatebox{90}{Long long heading 1~} & \rotatebox{90}{Long long longer longer heading 2~}\\ \hline %%%%%%%%%%% `~` is inserted at end of headings to keep the margin away
            Text 1 & Text 2\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note that both the headings are centrally aligned in the y-axis.
What I want is, the table headings are aligned at the bottom in the y-axis. In other words, the highlighted space would not be there.

[image]

Comment: That is normal: your `C` column type is based on the `m{}` columntype. Use the $p{}$ column type with a `\multicolumn`  for theses two headings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution as I suggested in a comment, and a simpler one, based on `eqparbox`:

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
\centering
        \begin{tabular}{|C{2em}|C{2em}|}\hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|p{2em}}{\centering\rotatebox[origin = l]{90}{Long long heading 1}~} &\multicolumn{1}{|p{2em}|}{\centering \rotatebox[origin = l]{90}{Long long longer longer heading 2~}}\\ \hline %%%%%%%%%%% `~` is inserted at end of headings to keep the margin away
            Text 1 & Text 2\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\qquad
        \begin{tabular}{|C{2em}|C{2em}|}\hline
            \rotatebox{90}{\eqmakebox[H][l]{Long long heading 1}~} & \rotatebox{90}{\eqmakebox[H][l]{Long long longer longer heading 2}~}\\ \hline %%%%%%%%%%% `~` is inserted at end of headings to keep the margin away
            Text 1 & Text 2\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Two cases with use of the `rotating` and `makecell` packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{Long Long longer longer heading 2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
\rothead{Long Long heading} 
                    & \rothead{Long Long longer longer heading 2} \\ 
    \hline
\makecell{Text\\ 1} & \makecell{Text\\ 2}   \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
or table design which I more prefer:
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{Long Long heading}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
\rothead{Long Long heading}
                    & \rothead{Long Long longer longer heading 2} \\
    \hline
\makecell{Text\\ 1} & \makecell{Text\\ 2}   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My proposal....

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\rotatebox{90}{Long Long heading~} & \rotatebox{90}{Long Long longer longer heading 2~} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text\\ 1\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text\\ 2\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but wanted to use `C` column-type for the actual body of the table,

Comment: @xxx--- You're welcome :-)...However...do you want that remove my answer? There is not problem.

Comment: No issues, please keep the answer. Stay safe during corona virus!

Comment: @xxx--- Thank you very much...and also for you "safe during COVID19. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

In `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a built-in command `\rotate` to do that. However, you have to rebuild `c` columns with `multicolumn` since you want to use your `C` type columns elsewhere.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{C{2em}C{2em}}[hvlines]
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\rotate Long long heading 1} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rotate Long long longer longer heading 2}\\ 
Text 1 & Text 2\\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of above code]